# Java SWT graphical context - How to get the color at the coordinates of a gradient rectangle?

Tags: java, swt, 2d, draw

I have a gradient rectangle, drawn with SWT graphical context.
How can I retrieve a color, which is used at a distinct point inside of the rectangle?

```
e.gc.setForeground(color_highlight_shadow);
e.gc.setBackground(color_normal_shadow);
e.gc.fillGradientRectangle(0, 1, 100, 100, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by copying the area (your pixel) into an image and extracting the RGB from this image:

```
final Image image = new Image(display, 1, 1);
e.gc.copyArea(image, x, y);

ImageData data = image.getImageData();

int pixelValue = imageData.getPixel(0,0);

PaletteData palette = data.palette; 
RGB rgb = palette.getRGB(pixelValue); 
System.out.println("RGB value for (x,y): " + rgb);
```